# time_select with 12 hour time and Time Zone in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface, timezone, time-select

I have the need to capture a time and time zone from users of a rails 2.3.8 app, but have been unable to think of a clean solution to create and parse the selections.

Ideally I would have a drop-down menus for the following:

- hour (1-12)
- minute (0-59)
- AM/PM
- Time Zone

Is there a gem/plugin that accomplishes what I am looking for? Will I need to store both the time and time zone in the database? What is the best strategy for storage?

I'll eventually need to spit these values out in UTC, but a user should be able to go back and review the time in the correct time zone.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do a 12 hour with AM/PM select element?

Comment: IIRC, there was a 12-hour time monkey patch. Not the cleanest solution, but it worked within my deadline.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get time zone selects with the appropriate methods:

- [time_zone_options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/time_zone_options_for_select)
- [time_zone_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/time_zone_select)

Similarly, there's [date_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select) for dates.

**Storage:**

If the timezone is specific to the user and doesn't change, then store their time zone in their user record and set it when you load the current_user.  Rails will convert times to/from UTC and always store UTC in the database and do the automatic convert to that default timezone for you (including daylight savings!).  Easiest way to do it.

[use_zone(zone)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Time/Zones/ClassMethods/use_zone) lets you override the default zone for a block, so you can accept a form value and set it with that function and set your value in that block.

UPDATE: I wrote up some [Rails timezone examples](http://databasically.com/2010/10/22/what-time-is-it-or-handling-timezones-in-rails/) as a blog entry.

Comment: I saw the methods to create a timezone selector, but that selector is not bound to a Time object. Is this binding something that I'll have to do myself?

Comment: A timezone won't be bound to a Time object.  Presumably, you're using `form_for @thing` on the thing that you're trying to capture the date/time/zone for.

Answer (score 1):

I personally used jQuery to change the display only:

```
 ampm = ["12 AM","01 AM","02 AM","03 AM","04 AM","05 AM","06 AM","07 AM","08 AM","09 AM","10 AM","11 AM","12 PM","01 PM","12 PM","01 PM","02 PM","01 PM","02 PM","03 PM","04 PM","05 PM","06 PM","07 PM","08 PM","09 PM","10 PM","11 PM"]
    j("#game_start_time_4i option").each(function(index,value){
        j(value).html(ampm[index]);
    });
```

Rails:

```
<%= datetime_select('game', 'start_time') %>
```