# Formatting the way a string is entered into my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, forms

I am wanting to format data entered into a string column (confusingly named `time`) of my database in a certain way. Because of legacy data issues on this project I can't simply change the column type from string to time because I would lose the old entries.

I simply want to require that the format of the information entered into the form and then submitted to the database is as follows:

`00:00 where a 0 can by any integer 0-9.`

How would I do that within a `form_for`.

I am using Rails 2.3.8.

Comment: You can change the field type, but it takes multiple steps. Whether it's worth it is the next question.

Comment: Yea...I don't really want to change the field type. Just looking for a way to format data going in.

Comment: If I was to change the field type...could the existing data be mapped?

Comment: Or, what about just validating such that the field contains numbers in the format of 00:00. Can that be done through a validation in the model?

Comment: If they are valid dates they should be mappable. You could write a bit of code to walk through the table, reading the time values and trying to parse and validate the ranges as a pre-flight test.

Answer (score 1):

A work around that might help:

First create a migration doing:

```
rename_column :the_models, :time, :old_time
add_column :the_models, :time, :time
```

So now, the model will have a field called `old_time` containing the original time data, and a new `time` field having the correct field type.

As a result, the existing forms would seems like lost all the time data, but at least they are calling `the_model.time` to get the result.

The real work around part:

```
class TheModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def time
    read_attribute(:time) || Time.parse(read_attribute(:old_time))
  end
end
```

So now the time value will be saved into the `time` filed.

When `time` is nil, it will try to get the time value from the `old_time` and convert it to a time object.

There are two drawbacks:

1. Time.parse("12:34") would give you something like: `2010-12-14 12:34:00 +0800`
   Because you gave it only the hr and min, other fields are not reliable.
2. You have a nearly deprecated field called `old_time` in the database. So in the future, you may want to completely remove that field, after you have confidence that all `old_time` values has been converted to the `time` field.

One more note:

You should convert existing forms, for `:time` field which probably using text_field.
The text_field may become showing something like `2010-12-14 12:34:00 +0800`.

If you really still want to use text_field, you could:

```
def time
  t = read_attribute(:time)
  t.nil? ? read_attribute(:old_time) : t.strftime("%H:%M")
end

def time=(val)
  write_attribute(:time, Time.parse(val))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would be `/\d\d:\d\d/`, but I'm not sure how to use regular expressions in Ruby.

Comment: Actually, that's not a regex. Perhaps you meant `\d`?

Comment: Eek! Yeah, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would be:

```
/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/
```

or

```
/\d\d:\d\d/
```

Here are some tests:

```
'00:00'[/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/] # => "00:00"
'12:00'[/\d\d:\d\d/]         # => "12:00"
'11:59'[/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/] # => "11:59"
'23:59'[/\d\d:\d\d/]         # => "23:59"

':'[/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/] # => nil
':0'[/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/] # => nil
'0:0'[/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/] # => nil
'000:0'[/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/] # => nil
'0:000'[/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/] # => nil
```

Up to this point I was working with your specified solution, but here's where it breaks down:

```
# BUG?
'1:00'[/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/] # => nil

# Fix?
'1:00'[/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}/] # => "1:00"

# *** BUG ***
'99:99'[/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/] # => "99:99"
```

Note that '99:99' is accepted.

Trying to use a regex to check the range is not really very workable when dealing with something like a time value. It can be done, but the regex becomes ugly.

Here's the start of a solution. Finishing the tests for appropriate range is left as an exercise for the reader:

```
timeval = '00:00'[/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/]
(timeval.split(':').map(&:to_i) <=> [11,59]) <= 0 # => true

timeval = '1:00'[/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}/]
(timeval.split(':').map(&:to_i) <=> [11,59]) <= 0 # => true

timeval = '1:00'[/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}/]
(timeval.split(':').map(&:to_i) <=> [11,59]) <= 0 # => true

timeval = '0:99'[/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}/]
(timeval.split(':').map(&:to_i) <=> [11,59]) <= 0 # => true

timeval = '99:99'[/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}/]
(timeval.split(':').map(&:to_i) <=> [11,59]) <= 0 # => false
```

Alternately, you might want to look into using some [`<select>` popups for the values](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html), or a jQuery plugin that is designed for time input, or something like [`validates_timeliness`](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) or [`validates_date_time`](http://svn.viney.net.nz/things/rails/plugins/validates%5Fdate%5Ftime/). I also found [time_select with 12 hour time and Time Zone in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993619/time-select-with-12-hour-time-and-time-zone-in-ruby-on-rails). You can [search Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=time_select) too.

Comment: Ok, so how would something like this be implemented? Would there be an addition to the Run model? Could you give me some specifics about what would go where (model, view). I am about 1.5 years into rails and so both reg expressions and testing aren't things I have mastered yet.